# Getting invalid signature for HMAC authentication of python pickle file

Tags: python, pickle, hmac

I am trying to use `HMAC` authentication for reading and write `pickle` files.

Sample Data :

```
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac
from datetime import datetime
import six
import pandas as pd
import pickle

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,2,3,4,5],
                   'score' : [720, 700, 710, 690, 670]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['abc', 'pqr', 'xyz'],
                   'address' : ['1st st', '2nd ave', '3rd st'] })

mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

mydict = {1 : 'p', 2 : 'q', 3 : 'r'}

obj = [df1, df2, mylist, mydict]
```

Write pickle file using:

```
data = pickle.dumps(obj)
digest =  hmac.new(b'unique-key-here', data, hashlib.blake2b).hexdigest()
with open('temp.txt', 'wb') as output:
    output.write(bytes(digest, sys.stdin.encoding) + data)
```

But when I try to read it back using:

```
with open('temp.txt', 'rb') as f:
    digest = f.readline()
    data = f.read()
    
recomputed = hmac.new(b'unique-key-here', data, hashlib.blake2b).hexdigest()
if not compare_digest(digest, bytes(recomputed, sys.stdin.encoding)):
    print('Invalid signature')
else:
    print('Signature matching')
```

I am getting `Invalid signature` as output. Could someone please help me understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: You need to add newline while writing data to file `output.write(bytes(digest, sys.stdin.encoding) + '\n' + data)` based on how you are reading the hash back.

Comment: @Jay I get this error `TypeError: can't concat str to bytes`

Comment: Try `output.write(bytes(digest, sys.stdin.encoding) + "\n".encode('ascii') + data)`

Comment: @Jay, that part worked but the main issue still stand: `compare_digest(digest, bytes(recomputed, sys.stdin.encoding))` I get `False`

Comment: You need to also strip the newline from `digest`. `digest = f.readline().rstrip()` should return `True` for compare_digest

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, thanks, I am very new to HMAC, learning here and there from the net and SO. If you could give an answer explaining what you said, it'd be immensely helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code illustrating what I think is a cleaner way to solve the problem.

```py
import hashlib
import hmac
import io
import os
import pickle

sample_obj = {'hello': [os.urandom(50)]}

data = pickle.dumps(sample_obj)

# write it out

my_hmac = hmac.new(b'my_hmac_key', digestmod=hashlib.blake2b)
my_hmac.update(data)
mac_result = my_hmac.digest()
pickle_out = io.BytesIO()
pickle_out.write(mac_result + data)

# read it in

pickle_in = io.BytesIO(pickle_out.getbuffer().tobytes())
my_hmac = hmac.new(b'my_hmac_key', digestmod=hashlib.blake2b)
mac_from_stream = pickle_in.read(my_hmac.digest_size)
data_from_stream = pickle_in.read()
my_hmac.update(data_from_stream)
computed_mac = my_hmac.digest()

# see if they match

print(hmac.compare_digest(computed_mac, mac_from_stream))
```

We avoid `hexdigest()` all together and thus eliminate unnecessary encoding and decoding. We create the mac instance and keep it around so that we can get the `hmac.digest_size` property. The use of `io.BytesIO` is just for illustrating the I/O part of your code.